# Send email with Gitlab docker image

Tags: email, docker, docker-compose, gitlab

Here's my goal, I would like to configure emails for my Gitlab server. I followed a lot of tutorials but I can't make it work.

My configuration is the following, I've got a reverse-proxy in a Docker container and my Gitlab server also in a Docker container.

About versions :

```
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21
```

Here's my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
   proxy: 
     external: true
   internal:
     external: false

services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    container_name: gitlab
    environment:
        - TZ=Europe/Paris
        - GITLAB_TIMEZONE=Paris
        - IMAP_USER=USER@GMAIL.COM
        - IMAP_PASSWORD=MYGMAILPASS
        - GITLAB_INCOMING_EMAIL_ADDRESS=USERGMAIL+%{key}@gmail.com
    volumes:
        - /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
        - /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
        - /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    restart: always
    labels:
        - traefik.backend=gitlab
        - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:git.domain.com
        - traefik.docker.network=proxy
        - traefik.port=80
        - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
    networks:
        - internal
        - proxy
```

I followed this tutorial which seems to be good :

https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#available-configuration-parameters

I must miss something in my configuration but I can't figure out what is it ...

Does anyone can help me to configure email sending ? I don't know either the proper way to test email sending from GitLab.

Is the best way is to configure from docker-compose environment variables or directly from gitlab.rb file ?

Some help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The instructions you followed are for a different docker image than the one you're actually using. You also set up IMAP, which is for receiving emails. In GitLab's case, it's for replying to issues by email.

What you want are the SMTP settings. The GitLab docker image does not come with sendmail installed, so you will have to follow the instructions here to set up SMTP in GitLab: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/smtp.html#example-configuration

You can dump gitlab.rb configuration right in your docker-compose under the `environment` section. My Fastmail setup for reference:

```yaml
environment:
    GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true 
        gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "***"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465    
        gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "***"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] = "***"
        gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = true
        gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true    
        gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your configuration directly into my gitlab.rb first. I configured Mailgun as SMTP and I tried to send email from "gitlab_rails console". It received the mail so I think SMTP is correctly configured. Is there a way to test it from Gitlab page ? To be sure everything work

Comment: So I did events on GitLab and I received email notification. Everything works perfect even when I set up gitlab.rb from docker-compose environment variables ! Thank for your help ! :)

Comment: @Hurobaki how did you managed to sent that email through gitlab_rails console? Can you post is somewhere, I can't find how to do this anywhere. I'm trying to debug email issues and it's really cumbersome to try to send email through GUI after every configuration change.

Comment: @MMT Of course, I know what you feel ! I don't know your configuration but when you enter to the gitlab_rails console you have to type this command : `Notify.test_email('destination_email@address.com', 'Message Subject', 'Message Body').deliver_now`

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to handle the smtp in a separated .env file and introduce it additionally into the compose under the same yaml key "GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG"? I would like to have the majority of logging / ssl setup directly in the docker compose, but would also like to commit it to version control. But the plaintext external smtp account password bugs me.

Something along the line of a docker-compose.yml with two entries in the environment key.

Comment: @Hurobaki I did that but I am receiving this error:
Delivered mail 67eb1cfcdc55d_4db2d00-415@gitlab.mysite.rs.mail (30150.7ms)

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/net-smtp-0.3.3/lib/net/smtp.rb:645:in `rescue in tcp_socket': Timeout to open TCP connection to mail.mysite.rs:465 (exceeds 30 seconds) (Net::OpenTimeout)

/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/socket.rb:61:in `connect_internal': Connection timed out - user specified timeout (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

Any ideas on how to fix this? I am running it in docker and I have opened 465 port.